# Where is the best place to put your ChangeNotifierProvider?

Tags: flutter, mvvm

I'm learning the `state management approache` called `Provider & Scope Model`.
I made an example and its working fine.

In my example I have a list of entries and a button "+" to add a new entry.

Both views have their own routes, as shown bellow:

```dart
 static Widget _buildRoute({
    @required BuildContext context,
    @required String routeName,
    Object arguments,
  }) {
    switch (routeName) {
      case Login:
        return LoginScreen();
      case OccurrenceentriesRoute:
         return  OccurrenceEntries();
      case OccurrenceFormRoute:
        Occurrence occurrence = arguments as Occurrence;
        return OccurrenceForm(occurrence: occurrence);
      default:
        throw 'Route $routeName is not defined';
    }
  }
}
```

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => OccurrenceProvider()..loadOccurrences(),
      child:  MaterialApp(
        title: 'Mapify',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => Routes.makeRoute(
                  context: context,
                  routeName: settings.name,
                  arguments: settings.arguments,
                ),
            maintainState: true,
            fullscreenDialog: false,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After reading the flutter documentation about the Provider approach I thought that would be a better idea to place the `ChangeNotifierProvider` as down as possible in the widget tree, as the documentation says:

> You don’t want to place ChangeNotifierProvider higher than necessary (because you don’t want to pollute the scope)

My first attempt was to use the `ChangeNotifierProviders` in my buildRoute, adding only the providers that i needed in each route. I did this, but the notifications made on one route don't affect the others... So, I'm really confuse, where should I place this ChangeNotifierProviders other than in the top of the `widget tree`?

Answer (score 1):

agree you really shouldn't place your change notifier at the top because that will rebuild the whole app instead

use [Multiprovider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/MultiProvider-class.html) and wrap it to the very top of you widget tree

```
    like... MaterialApp(
     child:MultiProvider(
         providers:[],
         child:yourWidget()
      ));

then you can access it by final var _sampleProvider = Provider.of<SomeModel>(context);
```

I suggest reading more into this if this explanation isn't still clear.

Comment: Thanks for answering Dean. Can you explain further? First you said to don't place my change notifier at the top and then, in the second line, you said "wrap it to the very top of your widget tree", ins't this contradictory? But yes, I will read more about this state management approach.

Comment: yeah sure, umm.. multiprovider doesn't run when your app is build unlike change nottifier provider. Multiprovider is a function that can call your providers in a somewhat global scope. If you know named routes its multiprovider is like that.